# Post category behave like a Post in back office menu

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories

I'm wondering if there is a trick to make a custom post category behave like a custom post so I can have multiples menu entries for each categories ?

[image]

Here we have two menu entries for two post types, I want to have multiple menu entries for one post type and multiple categories

Is it a good pratice ? Maybe I should make a class of that custom post and just make new instances ?

What's the best pratice ?

Comment: What do you mean “multiple menu entries”?

Comment: I don't understand either, can you edit your question to explain using different words and in greater detail?

Answer (score 0):

OK I finaly decided to create a PHP Class for that specific post type and call as many instances as needed.

I'm pretty sure that's the best approach, still listenning to all incoming advices